# If $f:A\to B\subseteq A$ is injective, then there exists a bijection $h:A\to B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please check whether my proof has any error! Thank you so much!

Theorem:

> If $f:A\to B\subseteq A$ is injective, then there exists a bijection $h:A\to B$.

Proof:

> Let $Y=A \setminus B$, and $X=\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}f^i(Y)$ where $ f^i(Y)=f(f(...f(Y)...)), i$ times.
>
> $f(X)=f(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}f^i(Y))=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}f(f^i(Y))=\bigcup_{i \geq1}f^i(Y)$.
>
> $X=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}f^i(Y) = f^0(Y) \cup (\bigcup_{i \geq1}f^i(Y))=Y \cup (\bigcup_{i \geq1}f^i(Y))=Y \cup f(X)$.
>
> To sum sup, $X=Y \cup f(X)$.
>
> $A \setminus X=(Y\cup B) \setminus (Y\cup f(X))=B \setminus f(X)$.
>
> We define $h:A\to B$ such that $h(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in X$, and $h(x)=x$ for all $x \in A \setminus X$, then $h$ is bijective.

Comment: Compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877323/schr%c3%b6der-bernstein-check-proof?rq=1

Comment: @RobertZ I'm still unable to figure out why the OP in that link need to prove $X$ is a union of disjoint sets. Could you please explain this difference?

Comment: Your final $h$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$ iff $f$ is injective in $X$  (trivial) and $f(X)=B\setminus (A\setminus X)$. If you show it your proof is fine.

Comment: Did you mean that I used $(Y\cup B) \setminus (Y\cup f(X))=B \setminus f(X)$ without giving proof for this identity? If so, here is my proof for that identity: $(Y\cup B) \setminus (Y\cup f(X))=((Y\cup B) \setminus Y) \cap ((Y\cup B) \setminus f(X))=B \cap ((Y\cup B) \setminus f(X))=(B \cap (Y\cup B)) \setminus f(X)=(B \cap A) \setminus f(X)=B\setminus f(X)$.

Comment: @RobertZ, I have presented a detail proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735694/suppose-that-z-subseteq-y-subseteq-x-and-that-fx-to-z-is-bijective-then, can you have a look at it and give some comments?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f:A \to B$ is injective, this implies that $|A| \leq |B|$. Now, since $B \subset A$, this implies that $|B| \leq |A|$. Combining these two inequalities, we have that $|A| =|B|$. Then, since $f$ is an injection, it is also a surjection and hence a bijection.

Comment: Do look at the pigeonhole principle!

Comment: The OP is trying to prove a theorem that implies the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, so using it doesn't help.

Comment: @egreg, That's what I'm trying to do. Did you see any error in my proof?

Comment: The Cantor–Bernstein theorem *is* the way to prove that $|A|\leq|B|$ and $|B|\leq|A|$ implies $|A|=|B|$. So as remarked by @egreg, this is entirely unhelpful as it would be circular. Unless, of course, you have a better way of proving that $\leq$ is antisymmetric on the cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, could you please give a comment on the correctness of my proof?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have presented a detail proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735694/suppose-that-z-subseteq-y-subseteq-x-and-that-fx-to-z-is-bijective-then, can you have a look at it and give some comments?